# How to fix this Java palindrome algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, palindrome

Solution as suggested by MrSmith42: Error in the p for loop. Fixing that corrected it.

I tried writing the code for question four of ProjectEuler.net archives. Need to find the largest palindrome which is a product of two 3-digit numbers.

I understand that this code is not the most efficient. For one, it goes upto 999,999. When the max should not exceed 999*999 = 998,001. I want to just get done with the problem. But I don't know if I can use Strings or String Tokenizer for this problem.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        int a = 100000, b = 10000, c =1000, d = 100, e = 10, f = 1;
        int m, n, p, q, s, t;
 //The plan is to increment the numbers by one, starting from 100,000 upto 999,999.
        for (m = 1; m <= 9; m++) {
            for (n = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
                for (p = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
                    for (q = 0; q <= 9; q++) {
                        for (s = 0; s <= 9; s++) {
                            for (t = 0; t <= 9; t++) {
                                if (t*a + s*b + q*c + p*d + n*e + m*f == m*a + n*b + p*c + q*d + s*e + t*f) {
                                    arr.add(m*a + n*b + p*c + q*d + s*e + f*t); }}}}}
            }
        }
        for (int x: arr)
            System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

I am getting numbers with the format ST00TS. So, not all the palindromes are covered. I can't figure out where I messed up.

Comment: sorry for the post being in quotes; I couldn't work out code formatting for the site. Nvm, /u/Lakshman edited the post. Thanks man.

Comment: You probably go from beginning to end in the loop.  You need to stop halfway through.  Otherwise you undo what was done when you loop over the first half.  Too many magic numbers for my taste.  Your code is unreadable.  I suspect it could be substantially simpler.

Comment: Instead of using 6 for loops to increment individual digits, why don't you just use one for loop that goes from 100_000 to 998_001?

Comment: Hey duffymo I agree with readability part. Honestly, I couldn't figure out another way. I figured out the way using math and tried to implement it with code. BTW could you explain "undoing the first part" bit? I am not following.

Comment: NegativeChameleon, thats because the palindrome requires the calculation of the numbers to be compared. I used the math formula: a(100,00) + b(10,000) + c(1,000) + d(100) + e(10) + f and the palindrome of this number should be f(100,000) + e(10,000) + ...

Comment: Note that your formula performs six checks, when only three checks are necessary: if the first digit equals the last digit, then the last digit is obviously equal to the first digit; same goes for the second and third digits.

Comment: How would i implement it with just 3 loops? Can't quite figure it out. I get your point though.

Comment: You need zero tests. If you want `t==m`, so replace one of them by the other and ditch one loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a copy and paste errors in the loop-header:

```
for (p = 0; p <= 9; p++) {  // not  (p = 0; n <= 9; n++)
```